# Handle data load - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm loading item data from Vuex into a component. When I refresh the page it needs a second or two to load the data which causes the page to break briefly:

[image: example of page breaking on refresh]

Is there a way I can handle this more gracefully? Even just a white screen would look better.

Comment: you know when the data is starting to fetch `isLoading = true`, and you know when you have all the data, set `isLoading = false`... with that variable, you can create smooth operations or as basic as `v-if="loading" ... v-else` ... there are nice loading components, like Youtube alike top color bar that could be nicer... another way, à-lá Facebook, load a [skeleton loader](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/skeleton-loaders/) while fetching data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can add a loader for that. Now a days many sites are showing beautiful loading icons or logos or messages when data is loading.For that check if data is loading then show  loaders else show data in that page.

Let's take a small example for what I mean.

```js
Vue.component('loading-screen', {
  template: '<div id="loading">Loading...</div>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isLoading: true
  },
  mounted () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isLoading = false
    }, 3000)
  }
})
```

```css
body
  margin 0

#loading
  background-color #63ab97
  color white
  font-size 32px
  padding-top 10vh
  height 100vh
  text-align center
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <loading-screen v-if="isLoading"></loading-screen>
  <h1 v-else>Hello world!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks really good, is there a way to detect if the page is actually loading instead of using ```setTimeout()```?

Comment: yes yes, just declare a variable isLoading=true in your data property and when u get response from api call then make isLoading= false. This way your problem can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a preloader on that page which loads for some seconds before displaying the actual page

Comment: Would that trigger if I navigated to the route normally? I only need it on page refresh

Comment: Yes it would @Daniel_Knights

Comment: @nitrocode, can u plz give some example in code what you mean ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way for exapmle:

You first create an component called for example `loader`

```
//loader.vue

<template>
   <div class="loader">
      <p>Loading...</p>
   </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
.loader {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   background: white;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 1000000;
}
</style>
```

Now you need to import your loader on that page where you need it. Then you add an `v-if` on it. You will need to add a new propertie to your state in your Vuex store.The `loading` propertie is on true initially. After you loaded everything you just set the `loading` to false and the component dissapear.

```
<template>
   <div>
      <loader v-if="$store.state.loading"></loader>
   </div>
</template>
import loader from "path/to/loader";
export default {
   components: {
      loader: loader
   }
}
```